# npm installation issue in windows

Tags: node.js, npm

executing command: npm --version and getting exception

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\anand\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\l
ib\config\defaults.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

please help me how to fix these, I tried to reinstall node.js but still it is not fixed.

Comment: Have you tried installing the module ? `npm install semver`

Comment: when I just run 'npm' command, its throwing that exception, tried but got same error

Comment: How did you install npm?

Comment: @silva I didn't install npm directly, I had installed node.js, so I think npm is inbuilt  to the node.js

Comment: Which version of node do you have installed? Have you tried uninstalling node and reinstalling it?